# Why is the derived class constructor is skipped?

Tags: c++

I have a code like this

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {cout << "Derived" << endl;}
};

int main() {
    Derived a(); // Only called base constructor
    Derived b;   // called derived constructor
}
```

What is the difference between these two calls? My understanding is that base constructor is always called before derived constructor? Why is the derived constructor skipped?

Thanks,

Comment: "Only called base constructor"  No it didn't.  This is a "vexing parse".

Comment: Notice that `Derived a()` [does not call any constructor](https://godbolt.org/z/pSdZTv).

Comment: @Gupta If you don't specify which base type constructor to use, it defaults to using the default constructor. Adding `Base()` has no effect, it's already implied.